# Stripe subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments, subscriptions

So I have a problem with Stripe.
My system works like this:
When a customer donates something, a defined percent of that amount gets in a sql table (for pay pal payment). This works fine, but subscriptions are destroying the system. I found no way how it's possible to trigger an action each month the customer is billing for the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into Stripe's [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). Whenever something happens in your Stripe account such as a customer creation, a charge or a transfer Stripe will send an event to your webhook endpoint (your code) so that it's aware of it. This allows you to email customers after a failed charge for example or be aware when funds have reached your bank account.

You would then be able to listen for different [events](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types) such as `invoice.payment_succeeded` when an invoice is paid or `invoice.payment_failed` when it failed and then update your database accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me a lot.